# How to stop a looped instanced sound in c#

Tags: c#, xna

Well im trying to make a system which decides which car sound to play when i accelerate, keep driving, slow down and idle.

Pretty much what happens is it ignores my .stop command for my looped sounds and then creates another instance and dosn't stop the other. I have tried many different ways of declaring my instanced sound but it just moans about any other way.

```
SoundEffectInstance CarIdleLooped = CarIdle.CreateInstance();
CarIdleLooped.IsLooped = true;
CarIdleLooped.Volume = 0.2f;
SoundEffectInstance CarFastlooped = CarFastloop.CreateInstance();
CarFastlooped.IsLooped = true;
CarFastlooped.Volume = 0.6f;

if (pad_p1.Triggers.Right == 0 && CarIdling == false && CarIsDriving == false)
{
    CarIdling = true;
    CarIdleLooped.Play();
}

if (pad_p1.Triggers.Right > 0 && CarIdling == true)
{
    CarIdling = false;
    CarIdleLooped.Stop();
    CarAccelerate.Play();
}
```

Comment: Instead of call Stop(), have you tried to create another instance?

Comment: also use fade in/out sound when changning sounds, to achieve overlapping. it will sounds better.